# Insert row (as list) into SQL table from F#

Tags: sql-server, list, insert, f#

In F#, suppose I have a MyType List List, where MyType can be a string, int, float, etc. Now suppose that each list in the list list represents a row in a table, so the list could look like:

```
`myList = [[1; "Foo", 15.0]; [2; "Bar", 8.3]; [3; "Zen" 19.5]]`
```

I want to insert each row into a database table that is predefined where the types match up, so the final table could look something like:

```
myTable ID    Name    Rating
        1     "Foo"     15.0
        2     "Bar"     8.3
        3     "Zen"     19.5
```

Is there an easy/good way to do this? I can match out the types from MyType, the problem I am looking to solve is if there is an easy way to insert a row into a table in F# if the row is in the form of a list. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried ADO.NET? An ORM? A SQL type provider? Where are you having problems?

Comment: I ended up just using string conversions to create an SQL query to insert the rows. Not the most elegant but it works

Comment: please be aware that that is the most common source of SQL injection vulnerabilities, which are still  the most common security vulnerabilities in the world.

Comment: Yes I'm aware, thanks